# Save a form in jsp with dropdown listfrom from database in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to save Account object in the hibernate .please find the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveAccount(@ModelAttribute("account") Account account,
            BindingResult result) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(account.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(account.getLastName());
        System.out.println(account.getSubject());
        System.out.println(account.getCity().getCityName());
        session.save(account);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/form.html");
    }
```

My jsp page have a form with First Name,Last Name ,city and subject fields.
I'm getting city dropdown fromatabase.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib
    prefix="c"
    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
<div class="container">
  <form  method="post" action="/sdnext/saveAccount.html">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName"   placeholder="Your name..">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastName"  placeholder="Your last name..">
    <label for="country">City</label>

<select name="city" id="cityName" >
    <c:forEach var="cityname" items="${lists}">
        <option value="${cityname.cityName}">${cityname.cityName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject"  placeholder="Write something.."  style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>       

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

DataBase bean classes are here

```
package test.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name= "Account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    private String firstName;

    private String LastName;

    @OneToOne
    private City city;

    private String subject;
}





package test.*;


@Entity
@Table(name= "City")
public class City implements Serializable {

  /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String cityName;

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

I have used one to one mapping to city object.But i'm not able to save city object in database,rest all firstNme,LastName and subjects are getting saved.its showing in network console,but data is not getting saved in database.Please help me fix this.Thanking you..

Comment: Would you show us your City class ?

Comment: I have added City class ..@sunkuet02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating the dto we can persists the values selected from the dropdown.and its working for me .

Answer (score 0):

`<option value="${cityname}">${cityname.cityName}</option>`

The problem is you are sending cityname.cityName (String) which cannot be mapped to City object so,
send the complete city object as the value. Hibernate will take care of mapping.